# R + Data frame name as string variable

Tags: r

I have a list of data frames, and I'm looking to assign to each data frame within the list a variable column that is simple a character vector of the given dataframe's  name.

```
data <- list(
    d1 = data.frame(animal = sample(c("cat","dog","bird"), 5, replace = T)),
    d2 = data.frame(animal = sample(c("cat","dog","bird"), 5, replace = T)),
    d3 = data.frame(animal = sample(c("cat","dog","bird"), 5, replace = T))
)
```

This yields:

```
> data 
$d1
  animal
1    cat
2   bird
3    cat
4    cat
5    cat

$d2
  animal
1    dog
2    cat
3    cat
4    cat
5   bird

$d3
  animal
1    cat
2    dog
3    cat
4    cat
5    cat
```

What I want to do is create something like the following:

```
> newdata 
$d1
  animal newvar
1    cat     d1
2    cat     d1
3    cat     d1
4    dog     d1
5    cat     d1

$d2
  animal newvar
1   bird     d2
2    cat     d2
3   bird     d2
4    cat     d2
5    cat     d2

$d3
  animal newvar
1   bird     d3
2   bird     d3
3    cat     d3
4    cat     d3
5   bird     d3
```

But I can't quite figure out how to actually reference the data frame name --in a list of data frames-- and turn it into a character vector appropriately.

Something like the following does not work:

```
namefunc <- function(x) {
    x <- x %>% transform(newvar = as.character(x))
}

newdata <- namefunc(data)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `Map` to `cbind` the corresponding `list` elements of 'data' with the `names` of 'data'

```
Map(cbind, data, newvar= names(data))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lapply(names(data), function(d) transform(data[[d]], newvar=d))
```

or eventually:

```
L <- lapply(names(data), function(d) transform(data[[d]], newvar=d))
names(L) <- names(data)
```